# Writing down $f_X$ explicitly (multidimensional normal distribution)

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

The probability density for a multidimensional normally distributed random vector $X$ is given as $f_X(s) := (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} det(\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} (s-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(s- \mu)}$.

Let $n = 2$, $X = (X_1, X_2)$, $\mu := \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$, $\Sigma := \begin{pmatrix}6.5 & -2.5 \\ -2.5 & 6.5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2.5 & -0.5 \\ -0.5 & 2.5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2.5 & -0.5 \\ -0.5 & 2.5 \end{pmatrix}$.

I just don't understand how to write down $f_X$ explicitly for the given parameters above. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Do you know how to invert a $2 \times 2$ non-singular matrix?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes. The inverse of $\Sigma$ is $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{13}{72}& \frac{5}{72} \\ \frac{5}{72} & \frac{13}{72} \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Then you can compute $(s-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(s-\mu)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is $\begin{pmatrix}s-1&s-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{13}{72}&\frac{5}{72}\\ \:\:\frac{5}{72}&\frac{13}{72}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}s-1\\ \:s-2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{36s^2-108s+85}{72}\end{pmatrix}$ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(s-\mu) = (s_1- 1 ~~~ s_2-2)$

Then by direct calculation:

$det(\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{6}$

$(s-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(s- \mu) = \frac{13}{72}(s_1-1)^2 + \frac{13}{72}(s_2-2)^2 + \frac{10}{72}(s_1-1)(s_2-2)$

Finally $\displaystyle f(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{1}{6} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{13}{72}(s_1-1)^2 + \frac{13}{72}(s_2-2)^2 + \frac{10}{72}(s_1-1)(s_2-2)\right)}$

Another option:

A simplified version for the bivariate normal is available. For example, see [this](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta104.1/Lectures/Lec22.pdf), page 3.

Note that $\mu_X = 1$, $\mu_Y = 2$, $\sigma_X = \sqrt{\frac{13}{2}}$, $\sigma_Y = \sqrt{\frac{13}{2}}$ and $\rho = -\frac{5}{13}$

Substitute the values and you are done. You can check the direct calculations by the second method.